# Salesforce Partner Program for Consulting Partners

Tags: partner

1. What is the cost for becoming a Salesforce Consulting Partner?
2. Is the fee monthly, annual, etc?
3. How long does the process take?
4. Brief overview of the steps involved in the process and approximately how long it takes to become a partner.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the cost for becoming a Salesforce Consulting Partner? Is the fee monthly, annual, etc?

The costs depend on a variety of factors, outlined in the [Consulting Program](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/consultants/Consulting_Program) and the [FAQ](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/consultants/Consulting_Program_FAQ). I'm not going to copy the entire thing because it may vary year to year. In summary, though, it's based on how good of a consultant you're rated as. The lowest **annual** fee is currently $750 USD, while the highest level is $25,000 USD.

Higher levels give you more visibility and generally get your organization referred to higher-profile clients. You can opt for a lower level (with the lower fees), but you'll reduce your referrals accordingly. Note that you'll need to hold at least two certifications, or two people with one certification each in order to meet the lowest level. Those also have additional costs. Read the linked article for more details. Read the "Consultant Benefits" resource at the end of the first link for additional info.

> How long does the process take?

It depends on the time of the year. It typically takes a few weeks to complete the process. Generally speaking, it will take as long as it takes. You can ask for how long the current wait is when you first talk to the Partner Program, but remember that it's not a concrete value. It depends on the current load. The docs suggest that the maximum time should be no more than a month.

> Brief overview of the steps involved in the process and approximately how long it takes to become a partner.

It's pretty easy. You fill out the [Partner Sign Up](https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/) form, and you'll be led through the process. Generally speaking, it will involve a validation process (verifying consultant credentials, etc), paying the annual fee, and signing contracts. Your total involvement in the process should only take a few hours. They've changed the process since I've been involved with it, but it's not terribly complex.

Comment: In addition to this question, what is counted or not counted towards the consultant level certification requirements? Meaning, do the consultants be full time employee? and any other criteria? @sfdcfox

Comment: @BerginPanimayam I don't know off the top of my head, and I'm not sure where I'd find that since it's not in the documentation I've linked. You might want to ask the partner team directly, or you can ask a new question, and I can bring it to their attention.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to contact them or post a new question.